# Set the height of subplot in a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Due to some constraints I am asked to draw a chart using matplotlib version 0.99 (Yes, I know it is very old but I can't challenge the decision...)

I use subplot to draw 2 charts within one figure

```
import matplotlib as plot

full_chart = plot.figure(figsize = (80,100), dpi=100)
first_chart = plot.subplot(211)
second_chart = plot.subplot(212)
```

However, system will automatically set the ratio of 2 charts to be 50% each.

The question is:
can I change the height of the 2 subplots, so that I can adjust the display ratio for each subplot?

Thank you!

Comment: I think [gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) was already present in matplotlib 0.99. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately gridspec is not yet available at 0.99, thank you anyway.